# Is there a way to make the Project Collection Build Service Accounts update work items?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

I'm running a script in a pipeline that updates work items (via REST APIs) and its been running for a year, now rather than renewing the token this year and every year, I decided to use the System.AccessToken in the script.

In addition to updating work items, the script runs various other APIs, the Access token works fine for those, but when it comes time to edit the work items I get hit with the error:
"You don't have bypass rules permission.
Please contact your collection administrator to grant this permission for enabling this
action."

I've enabled these permissions for the Project Collection Build Service Account:

- "Edit Work Items in this Node" (Under Project Settings/Project Configuration/Root Area path)
- "Bypass rules on work item updates" (In org settings, after trying this I then added it to the build administrator group for the relevant project, gave the same permission there as well)

But none of these worked.

Finally I want to ask, is it possible to get the Project Collection Build Service Accounts to update work items?

Please note, I'm only attempting to updating the state of the work item.

*EDIT
Adding the yaml script:

```
trigger:
- main

pool: 'Default'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        # Define variables
        $PersonalAccessToken = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
        $ApiUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)/_apis/wit/workitems/415682?bypassRules=true&api-version=6.0"

        $wiBodyTemplate = "[{`"op`": `"add`",`"path`": `"/fields/System.State`",`"value`": `"Ready for QA`"}]"
        $Base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PersonalAccessToken)"))

        # Send the PATCH request
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -contentType 'application/json-patch+json' -Body $wiBodyTemplate -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $Base64AuthInfo"} -uri $ApiUrl 

        # Output the response
        $response | Format-Table -AutoSize
        $response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Check whether your pipeline is configured to run in the scope of the project or the collection. If it's the former, you should change the permissions of the `Project Build Service Accounts`.

Comment: Can you share the YAML?

Comment: Done, I added my yaml pipeline to the question above. Do note that when I execute the same powershell script in a classic pipeline (and having enabled the "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" in the Agent Job), it works fine and updates the work item state with no problem but the same doesn't work in yaml

Comment: Tested your YAML and after adjusting the permissions things are working. It might be that your environment has other permissions defined at a more granular level that takes away these permissions again.

Comment: You might be right, I'll have to look into this a bit deeper, I'll start off testing it in a new organization.

Comment: But then again, the same script is working in classic, what is up with that?

Comment: Can't tell. My guess would be that classic is using another account than the one YAML depends on. I haven't used Classic builds in this way in forever, I consider them deprecated,

Answer (score 2):

`Project collection build service (org)` account is able to update the work item state in rest api:
[image]

To bypass the rule with the account, please follow below items to have a check:

1. Go to project settings -> Pipelines -> Settings -> make sure you **toggled off** the option `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines`. If it's toggled on, the pipeline will use project scoped build service account.

[image]

2. Add [bypassRules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-reference?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance#bypass-rules) parameter to true in rest api.

My yaml below:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
      $Uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)/_apis/wit/workitems/485?bypassRules=true&api-version=7.0"
      Write-Host $Uri
      function CreateJsonBody
      {
          $value = @"
      [
        {
          "op": "add",
          "path": "/fields/System.State",
          "value": "Active"
        }
      ]
      "@
       return $value
      }
      $json = CreateJsonBody
      $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers $header
```

3. To bypass the rule, you also need to get `Bypass rules on work item updates` permission for collection build service account. Go to project settings -> permissions -> create a new group -> add `Project collection build service (org)` account as member, then you can set the permission for the account.
   [image]

[image]

Pipeline works:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wade for the answer but I've tried and re-tried all the points you've listed and it doesn't work in YAML & IDK why.

I've done some extensive testing on my project as well and this is what I found:
- Your script works in Classic, no problem
- I paste the same script into a simple yaml pipeline and it fails. I've also added the
 "env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)"
Just after declaring the powershell task in yaml and even then it returns the same error

Comment: I get the powershell task from your yaml, and it works on my side. Is your yaml pipeline  in same project with the classic pipeline(working one)? This is in order to make sure the permission have been granted for the account. I notice you are using `default` pool which should be a self-hosted agent, is it same with classic one? Please also make sure there's no other tasks to define the $(system. accesstoken) value in yaml pipeline.

Comment: Hi Wade, yes these pipelines are in the same project and configured the same way. I tested this first in Classic and after it worked I copied over the exact same inline script into a new yaml pipeline and added that Oauth token to the script as shown in my question.

I've also followed the same steps to permit the Build service accounts to edit work items.

Comment: To make sure, when you say classic pipeline, it's build classic pipeline not release classic pipeline, is it correct? Cause on project settings, there are two different options for non-release and release identity scope. In addition, have you checked the agent, what if you choose Microsoft-hosted agent?

Comment: Yes that is correct the classic pipeline I was talking about was a classic build pipeline.
I tried using MS hosted agents and I was still getting the same error in the Yaml pipeline.

Comment: We ran the test in another testbed organization of ours and its working there. We have double and triple checked the Build service account permissions in both orgs and they're the same yet in the main org this script is not working with the System.AccessToken variable. What could we be missing?

Comment: Quite strange. If you `echo $(System.AccessToken) >> test.txt`, and publish the txt as artifact, check the artifact content, does the token looks like `eyJ0eXAiOXXXXXXXX`(more than 4 lines)? If it's not please check if you overwrite the token in yaml(variable, pre-task setting...etc). If the token looks fine, please check if you are backing both orgs to same AAD?

Comment: Hi Wade, we tried your suggestion and found the token to look the same as you mentioned (eyJ0eXAiOiJ.....)

"If the token looks fine, please check if you are backing both orgs to same AAD?" Could you clarify on this for me please?

Comment: You can go to Organization settings -> Azure Active Directory, check if both organization has same setting(link to same AAD?). If it's same, but system.accesstoken still doesn't work in yaml, you could need to raise a support ticket from azure portal, asking DevOps product team to help fix for you.

Comment: Thanks Wade, I'll probably raise a request with MS.
We have done some more tests and replicated the same in another project in the same Org and its working fine in both Yaml and classic build pipelines in that other project.

Comment: @KevinLee, sure. You can add a comment when it's resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two users that control what the agent can do. It depends on the configuration of the [pipeline, whether it's scoped to the Project Collection or the Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scoped-build-identities).

> Azure DevOps uses two built-in identities to execute pipelines.
>
> - A collection-scoped identity, which has access to all projects in the collection (or organization for Azure DevOps Services)
> - A project-scoped identity, which has access to a single project
>   These identities are allocated permissions necessary to perform build/release execution time activities when calling back to the Azure DevOps system. There are built-in default permissions, and you may also manage your own permissions as needed.
>
> The collection-scoped identity name has the following format:
>
> - `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})`
>   For example, if the organization name is fabrikam-tailspin, this account has the name Project Collection Build Service (fabrikam-tailspin).
>
> The project-scoped identity name has the following format:
>
> - `{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})`
>   For example, if the organization name is fabrikam-tailspin and the project name is SpaceGameWeb, this account has the name SpaceGameWeb Build Service (fabrikam-tailspin).
>
> By default, the collection-scoped identity is used, unless configured otherwise as described in the previous Job authorization scope section.

It might be that your pipeline has been configured at the "Project" level, in which case you've [granted the wrong user permissions to edit the work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manage-build-service-account-permissions).

I just ran your YAML script and made the following changes to make it work:

1. I created a Build Service Accounts group in the Project
2. I added the *Project Collection Build Service* and the *{Project} build service* accounts to this group.

   [image]
   [image]
3. I added the Build Service Accounts as a member of the Contributors group.
   [image]
4. I changed the Bypass permissions for the Build Service Accounts group:
   [image]

With only these changes the script succeeds with a work item in the same Project as the pipeline:

[image]

Comment: I've granted both the Build Service User account ({Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})) and the group Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName}) permission to edit work items but I'm still running into this issue